# use ForceReply option to get input from user without reply interface in telegram

Tags: laravel, telegram, telegram-bot

We know that there is [ForceReply](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forcereply) option to get input from user in telegram api.

Telegram said :

> Upon receiving a message with this object, Telegram clients will
>   display a reply interface to the user (act as if the user has selected
>   the bot‘s message and tapped ’Reply'). This can be extremely useful if
>   you want to create user-friendly step-by-step interfaces without
>   having to sacrifice privacy mode.

Now I used [irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk) to make my telegram bot. in that package to create a `force_reply` interface we should do like this :

```
$forceReply = Keyboard::forceReply(['force_reply' => true]);

$this->replyWithMessage([
    'text'         => 'Please enter your name ?',
    'reply_markup' => $forceReply
]);
```

Result is like :

[image]

But in usages in other bot for example [PollBot](https://t.me/PollBot) that uses this option , when shows a question and want to get answer , reply interface does not show.

I want to do same.I know that if I set value of `force_reply` to `false` it done but I do not know after that how can I detect that text that user entered is related to which my question.

what do I do really ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I've done for my last bot is:

I created a table for **user history** which holds some info about users like their username and chat_id, I also keep track of a user's *last state* in **last_state** column

So when asking a question from a user, I update her state field in DB with current state, Then upcoming answer is for the question in user's last state, Let me go with a short-simple example.

A:Propmpt question *x* for user with chat_id *n*

B:Update state of user whose chat_id is *n* equal to *x* in DB

C:Get the answer

D:Get **chat_id** and then fetch her **last_state** from DB, the state indicares the question

Now you know which question she's answering to

*Check this bot developed by me:  @TunnelCSBot*

Comment: we know that answer is a simple text. I have many simple text that user can enter and do some jobs. my question is that how can I detect that text that user entered is a answer for last question of a simple text command

Comment: I told you, save user states